# how to find whether this python list within list contains duplicates or not?

Tags: python-2.7

I have the following python list :-

```
a=[['t1', ['a', 'c']], ['t2', ['b']], ['t2', ['b']]]
```

now it contains duplicate lists within it `['t2', ['b']]` 2 times
I want to return true if the list contains duplicates.
Can anyone please help me how to do so ?

I tried to use the set function but it is not working here !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are free to represent your list `a` as a list of tuples/records:

```py
b = [(item[0], tuple(item[1])) for item in a]
```

(or, in the first place):

```py
a = [('t1', ('a', 'c')), ('t2', ('b')), ('t2', ('b'))]
```

Then the items become hashable and you can use `collections.Counter`:

```py
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(b)
```

So you can find duplicates like:

```py
duplicated_items = [key for key, count in c.iteritems() if count > 1]
```

(Or you can use set):

```py
has_duplicates = len(set(b)) < len(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to remove duplicates, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24582741/2991872) might be helpful:

```
unique_a = [i for n, i in enumerate(a) if i not in a[:n]]
```

You can rewrite it this way:

```
has_duplicates = lambda l: True in [(i in l[:n]) for n, i in enumerate(l)]
```

You can call it this way:

```
has_duplicates(a)   # True
```